# WinFlash does not support this BIOS update – EZ-Flash needs admin password

Tags: passwords

I have an ASUS X556UA laptop, which is on BIOS 304. I have recently come across a virus which has hijacked my browser and is not allowing me to do much or install removal tools, etc.

I want to reinstall Windows, although I haven't been able to, since I apparently set an admin password at some point. 
I have researched many ways to remove the password.

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> for recovery password doesn't work apparently because of the older BIOS version. 
I can't use EZ-Flash, since I have only user access to the BIOS.

WinFlash doesn't work on that version of the BIOS.

My name does appear on the BIOS luckily,
so I might be able to take it to a service center. 
But for now, I am stuck and need help!

Comment: Setting a password on the BIOS is not something to be done lightly. It is imperative that you save that password in several locations to make sure you don't lose it, because when you lose it, it requires qualified hardware assistance to clear it, likely by replacing the mainboard that the BIOS is embedded on.